# $\mathrm{Out}(G)\times\mathrm{ Out}(H)$ is a finite index subgroup of $\mathrm{Out}(G\times H)$

Tags: gr.group-theory

When $G$ and $H$ are indecomposable centerlesss groups it is known that $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\times \mathrm{Aut}(H)\cong\mathrm{Aut}(G\times H)$ if $G\ncong H$ and $\mathrm{Aut}(G)\times \mathrm{Aut}(H)$ is an index $2$ subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(G\times H)$ if $G\cong H$. Same holds for $\mathrm{Out}$. My question is, are there any other known conditions on $G$ and $H$ that imply that $\mathrm{Out}(G)\times\mathrm{ Out}(H)$ is a finite index subgroup of $\mathrm{Out}(G\times H)$?

Edit: I'm trying to understand certain virtual properties of the outer automorphism group of a right-angled Artin group (RAAGs). In those groups, the defining graph $\Gamma$ gives a canonical decomposition of the group $A_\Gamma$ as a direct product of indecomposable groups. Hence, if for a decomposition of the form $A_\Gamma=A_{\Gamma_1}\times\dots\times A_{\Gamma_n}$ it holds that  $\mathrm{Out}(A_{\Gamma_1})\times\dots\times\mathrm{Out}(A_{\Gamma_n})$ has finite index in $\mathrm{Out}(A_\Gamma)$ the problem would be simplified a lot. If $A_\Gamma$ is centerless the result holds by the above reason, but if $A_\Gamma$ has non-trivial center there must be some copies of $\mathbb{Z}$ in the decomposition and I don't know if in this case we have finite index or not.

For a more concrete example. If $G=F_{k_1}\times\dots \times F_{k_n}\times \mathbb{Z}^a$ with $a\geq 1$, does it hold that $\mathrm{Out}(F_{k_1})\times\dots\times \mathrm{Out}(F_{k_n})\times \mathrm{Out}(\mathbb{Z}^a)$ has finite index in $\mathrm{Out}(G)$?

Comment: yes: both groups being finite

Comment: @I.Haage True, but that is trivial. What about infinite groups?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think there should be a theorem?  Seems like every example I can think of does not allow for any theorem of this sort.

Comment: @Marcos: if you have a specific example in mind, it’s probably better just to give it.

Comment: @RyanBudney I don't have any particular reason, but I'll edit the question to give more details on the problem I'm working to make the question more specific.

Comment: The answer to the concrete question at the end is "no" thanks to, for example, the $n=1$, $k_1=1$, $a=1$ case. In this case you have $\mathrm{Out}(\mathbb{Z}^2)$ which is infinite, but $\mathrm{Out}(\mathbb{Z})\times \mathrm{Out}(\mathbb{Z})$ is finite. If you insist on the $F_{k_i}$ being non-abelian then it should still be "no", I guess thanks to something like transvections from the $\mathbb{Z}^a$ factor having no proper power land in that direct product.

Comment: $F_k \times \mathbb Z$ is a counterexample. It has an Eilenberg-Maclane space obtained from $k$ copies of $S^1 \times [0,1]$ by identifying all $2k$ boundary components to a single copy of $S^1$; for an equivalent description, just take the product of an $n$-petalled rose with $S^1$. If $A$ is one of those annuli corresponding to a free basis element $a$ of $F_n$ and if $\tau$ is the Dehn twist around $A$ then $\tau^n(a) = a z^n$ (where $\mathbb Z = \langle z \rangle$), so the infinite cyclic group $\langle \tau \rangle$ has no powers contained in the $Out(F_k) \times Out(\mathbb Z)$ subgroup.